# Negate value on condition?

Tags: c#

I have the following:

```
public Boolean Test(Boolean value, Boolean negation) {
  return negation ? !value : value;
}
```

So `value` is negated only if `negated` is true. Otherwise `value` is returned either it is true or false.

Is there any operator to do this as an alternative of what I am doing?

Comment: That would be `return negation ^ value;`.

Comment: @code4life `Boolean` is a legal type in .NET.

Comment: Yeah I just realized that too...  :-)

Comment: I'd just like to point out a lot of programmers struggle with XORs.  Even for people who understand XORs, if you don't use them a lot, you have to stop and think about what negatiion ^ value really means.  I'd be tempted to leave the function the way you have it -- the intention is a lot more clear -- and rely on the compiler/JIT optimizing it to a XOR automatically (unless you found it wasn't and it was causing a performance problem).

Comment: @Steven That’s actually a very good point!

Comment: @Steven did not read this, my point too

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To find an operator for boolean operations, you should consider creating a [truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) to see all the possible outcomes. In your case, there are two inputs `value` (`V`) and `negation` (`N`):

```
N V | Result
0 0 | 0
0 1 | 1
1 0 | 1
1 1 | 0
```

As you can see, you return true only one of `N` and `V` are true. That’s an [exclusive or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or#Truth_table).

In C#, that’s the operator `^` (xor), so you can just write your function like this:

```
public bool Test(bool value, bool negation)
{
    return negation ^ value;
}
```

Comment: The only downside to this is readability for some people. This topic can be found in refactoring books. when this is used in method it might not always be clear or readable, where traditional if statements makes the logic more readable. In your case with a small method it might not be the case.

Comment: Of course, when you're shortening a ~20 character expression, you're not exactly adding clarity ;)